# Will Xcode 4.1.1 work with iOS 5?

Tags: xcode, ios5, compatibility

I am an iOS developer and i was simply wondering, if I would be able to continue using Xcode 4.1.1 and test my application on iOS 5 for iPhone if i were to update.

I've tried looking for the answer quite a few times but I get conflicting answers.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to ask that is the Apple DevForums as iOS 5.0 is still under NDA.

https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/